# Why is Daenerys unharmed after the events of "Fire and Blood"?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the "Baelor" and "Fire and Blood" episodes of *Game of Thrones*, I was confused by Daenerys's story. Her shaky authority and her heretical actions put her in danger. In "Baelor", Jorah said things to the effect of:

> This isn't Westereos where men honor blood. Here they only honor strength. There will be fighting here after Drogo dies. Whoever wins that fight will be the new Khal. He won't want any rivals. Your boy will be plucked from your breast and given to the dogs.

And later:

> We could have been 10 miles away from here by now on the way to Asshai. You would have been safe.

I interpreted those comments to mean that there were many Dothraki vying to be Khal and most of them would try to kill her. However, in "Fire and Blood", Daenerys is unharmed. Did I miss the part in "Fire and Blood" where they explained why Daenerys was unharmed by the bloodriders? I realize that when

> Jorah killed Qotho,

that put an end to some of the danger, but he was just one of many Dothraki. What was stopping them from killing Daenerys and her unborn child? In "Fire and Blood" why do they just leave without doing what Jorah said they would do? Is this explained more in the book?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It wasn't Dany that Jorah was afraid would be killed, but her son, Khal Drogo's successor. According to Dothraki custom when a khal dies, his wife is sent back to Vaes Dothrak (their capital city) to live out the rest of her life as a member of the Dosh Khaleen, widows of Khals who offer wisdom to the rest of the Dothraki. They were the ones that gave the prophecy that Dany's son would be "The Stallion that Mounts the World" in the heart eating scene.

Since her son was already dead, the Khalasar just left her. Her bloodriders stayed, since it was their final duty to escort her back to Vaes Dothrak. Which is a fate that Jorah knew Dany wouldn't desire, so he counseled flight.

Answer (score 6):

In the book most of the Khalasar simply leaves with a new leader, leaving behind a few women and old men.  Drogo's bloodriders also stay with Denny, because their final duty is to bring her back to Vaes Dothrak, where she would grow old with other former Khaleesis, and then to kill themselves.  When a Khal dies, his bloodriders are supposed to die too.

To find out what actually happens, you would have to read the books, or wait for Season 2. ;)

By the way, Jorah said that they could have been on their way to [Asshai](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Asshai), which is a mysterious city in the far East, home to all sorts of magic.

Comment: i didn't know any of this answer, great answer.